# What does self: Box<Self> mean?

Tags: rust

I'm reading Rust Programming book. in Chapter 17 i can not understand this:

```
self: Box<Self>
```

You can easily explain?

Comment: it's something you can ignore for now.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's give a bit of a context, as described in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html):

```
trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
}
```

A bit further below in the book, it's explained:

> We’ve added the `request_review` method to the `State` trait; all types that implement the trait will now need to implement the `request_review` method. Note that rather than having `self`, `&self`, or `&mut self` as the first parameter of the method, we have `self: Box<Self>`. This syntax means the method is only valid when called on a `Box` holding the type. This syntax takes ownership of `Box<Self>`, invalidating the old state so the state value of the `Post` can transform into a new state.

Let me give you an example. Say we have a struct `A` that implements `State`:

```
struct A {}

impl State for A {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State> {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

If we tried this code:

```
let a = A {};
a.request_review();
```

, we would get a compiler error. However, if we tried the code below, there would be no problem:

```
let a = A {};
Box::new(a).request_review();
```

Comment: Very interesting. I always just assumed the options were `self`, `&self`, and `&mut self`, but it seems that there are [several others](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#methods)

Comment: And [arbitrary self types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44874) would mean "any type that can dereference to `Self`" would be allowed. Very neat!